# Error "No such file or directory " is displayed when executing ruby rspec scripts from Atom editor

Tags: ruby, rspec, atom-editor

On executing ruby rspec scripts from Packages->Rspec -> Run Current Spec in Atom (E.g File1_spec.rb ) , I get the error “/usr/bin/bash: line 1: cd: C:Usersnamep.atom: No such file or directory
e[He[J”  .

Setup/Changes done in Atom : 
1. Using "Add Project Folder" , added the repo from GitHub folder that was already present in my system locally
 and then access the scripts for execution .

2. Added the package Atom RSpec runner package.
3. Edited config.cson to include rspec command . Contents below :

“*”:
core:
projectHome: “C:\Users\MyFolder\Documents\GitHub\”
telemetryConsent: “no”
rspec:
command: “rspec”

Please help on how to fix this . TIA .

Comment: Are you able to run `rspec` from the command line (terminal, aka shell)?

Comment: When i run from the command line , this is the error i get :                                                
An error occurred while loading ./File_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require 'spec_helper'

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- spec_helper
# ./File_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./File_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.001 seconds (files took 0.29084 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples

Comment: Then you are trying to load a nonexistent file.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard The spec_helper is present inside the spec folder . The issue happens only when executing the script in Atom. This works fine in RubyMine. What could be the issue with Atom ? Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `require_relative` with the relative directory instead of `require`? Maybe RubyMine is automatically putting the spec directory in the load path but that is not happening on the command line?

Comment: I changed require to require_relative but still the same error is displayed ..